# cross domain request in Xhtml

Tags: cors, xhtml, xmlhttprequest-level2, hbbtv

I'm trying to send a https request from a HbbTV-Application (xhtml) to get information from https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp.

XMLHttpRequest was my first option, but due to same origin policy it obviously won't work. As an alternative i found CORS, but as I understand it it needs XMLHttpRequest2, which is part of HTML5, am I correct?

Is there any function, method or workaround I could use to achieve my goal?

Best regards
Adrian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Comment: Note, in particular, the section titled "Alternatives to CORS" in the accepted answer on the duplicate question.

Comment: "it needs XMLHttpRequest2, which is part of HTML5" — XMLHttpRequest and HTML are independent specifications with no dependencies between them.

Comment: [This HbbTV documentation](https://www.hbbtv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/HbbTv-Security-2015.pdf) implies that it supports CORS. Have you tested to see if it is supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest was my first option, but due to same origin policy it obviously won't work.

I don't get it.

From here on stackOverflow I have no trouble running an XHR on the endpoint you provided, using the following snippet :

```js
function fetchData() {
  var URL = 'https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        document.getElementById('response')
          .innerHTML = "Response: " + xhr.responseText
      }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', URL)
  xhr.send()
}
```

```html
<div id='response' onclick='fetchData()'>Click to fetch</div>
```

CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) is more a specification than a technology in itself.

It defines that cross-origin request should be allowed only if the destination endpoint specifies that the origin is allowed to fetch there.
If you wish to learn more about it, I recommend this excellent article on MDN : [HTTP Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Also, if your platform supports it or you can polyfill it, I recommend you use Fetch instead of XHR.

Comment: oh man, thank you a lot. I was so focused on documentations and different solutions, that I changed the GET into a POST in some point, so much time wasted. Thanks for all of your help.